# NAudio - Playback stops if called Play() again

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm programming a game and using NAudio with WaveOut. The sound is played when a collision occurs. The problem is the sound plays some times and after a few seconds if the collision happens again, the sound isn't played. I'm using this code.

```
WaveOut device = new WaveOut();
WaveStream source = new Mp3FileReader("hit.mp3");

device.Init(source);
```

And to play it,

```
source.Position = 0;
source.CurrentTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
device.Play();
```

Am I forgetting anything?

Thanks.

Comment: what is exception?i think sound paused after two play .

Comment: Dose you make new `WaveOut device = new WaveOut();` and `WaveStream source`  for each paly?

Comment: No. They are made only once. The device is a class level variable and I'll play it by calling the above statements.

Comment: @IRSOG No. No exception is thrown. The sound plays for 10-15 times and then it never plays again.

Comment: :if make new WaveOut for each call dose it happen again?

Comment: @IRSOG I can't create new instance of it every time. The main game slows down.

Comment: Got it working. It's playing if I call `Init()` again before each play.

Comment: you dispose sound after it's played.test it,but instead of using it's better using fmod some of popular game engine use fmod.i use it a lot,its very good for this

Answer (score 0):

Try take a look at this instruction, by Mark Heath, on how to use NAudio for "fire and forget" audio playback:

http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/fire-and-forget-audio-playback-with.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've already started using OpenAL.